# Convert .mht files to pdf files using java

Tags: pdf, mhtml, java

Is it possible to convert MHTML(.mht) files to pdf with proper css rendering.
Tried using pd4ml but the extenal css and links refered in .mht file fails to get loaded in the pdf genrated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try unpacking the MHTML to HTML and separate files, then using your pd4ml method to generate the PDF.

[Chilkasoft Java MHT](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-mht.asp) is one solution you can look into, although after the 30 day trial you will need a license.